# What does parentheses mean after list brackets in python

Tags: python

I saw a question they wanted me to make a function to calculate the area of some shapes
the example code is below, I just don't understand what do that parenthesis work after brackets and how can I create a function to solve the question this way

code:

```
ls = area_func(['square', 'circle', 'rectangle', 'triangle'])

print(ls[0](1))
print(ls[1](2))
print(ls[2](2, 4))
print(ls[3](4, 5))
```

output:

```
1
12.566370614359172
8
10.0
```

Comment: What is `area_func`?

Comment: If it returns a list, then the parenthesis are subscript (and the value inside them is the index).

Comment: If it returns a function, then the parenthesis are the function-call script (and the value inside them is the parameter passed to that function).

Comment: It means that `ls` is some sort of collection, probably a tuple or list. This list contains functions that can be called with arguments. Brackets are for index/key lookup, parentheses imply that an object is callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I assume that area_function return 4 functions as list like

```
def area_func():
  def square(x):
     return  x*x
  # other functions
  return [square,circle, rectangle, triangle]
```

and from this code, below it seems like you are calling these function at index 0,1,2,3

```
print(ls[0](1)) # ls[0] has reference to square function
print(ls[1](2)) # ls[1] has reference to circle function
print(ls[2](2, 4)) #ls[2] has reference to rectangle function
print(ls[3](4, 5)) #ls[3] has reference to triangle function
```

So, essecially doing

```
ls[0](1)
```

is equivalent to

```
square(1)
```

Comment: totally correct i had to make functions that return formula for each shape and return the functions in a list in area_func thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could be many different things, for example - scope for passing parameters to a function:

```
def area_func(arr):
    return [func1, func2, func3, func4]

def func1(x):
    return '1'

def func2(x):
    return '12.566370614359172'

def func3(x, y):
    return '8'

def func4(x, y):
    return '10.0'

ls = area_func(['square', 'circle', 'rectangle', 'triangle'])

print(ls[0](1))
print(ls[1](2))
print(ls[2](2, 4))
print(ls[3](4, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

`area_func` returns a list of functions.

Then the functions are call with different parameters.

`ls[0]` probably computes the area of a square, `ls[1]` for circle, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The area func is probably supposed to generate a list of functions based on the input given to it, so calling it with `['circle','square']` for example should return a list with just those two functions, in the specified order? For that, you probably want to have a dictionary of functions, something like this:

```
def area_func(func_list):
    def square(x): 
    def circle(r):
    def rectangle(h, w):
    def triangle(h, b):
 
    funcs = {'square':square, 'circle':circle, 'rectangle':rectangle,   
             'triangle':triangle}                              

    return [funcs.get(x) for x in func_list if funcs.get(x) is not None]  #avoids KeyError
```

Dictionaries of functions are a common way to do this kind of thing.